# How do I make a bitwise and in a bat-file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, bit-manipulation

I have tried with the following, but it just says "& was unexpected at this time."

```
@echo off
:enter-input
echo Please enter a number between 1 and 15:
echo 1 = Selection one
echo 2 = Selection two
echo 4 = Selection three
echo 8 = Selection four
echo x = Quit

set INPUT=
set /P INPUT=Type number: %=%

if "%INPUT%" == "" goto enter-input
if "%INPUT%" == "x" goto end
if "%INPUT%" == "X" goto end

set /A %INPUT%
if %INPUT% & 1 == 1 echo Selection one
if %INPUT% & 2 == 2 echo Selection two
if %INPUT% & 4 == 4 echo Selection three
if %INPUT% & 8 == 8 echo Selection four

echo Done
:end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way of doing this.

```
@echo off
:enter-input
echo Please enter a number between 1 and 15:
echo 1 = Selection one
echo 2 = Selection two
echo 4 = Selection three
echo 8 = Selection four
echo x = Quit

set /P INPUT=Type number:

if "%INPUT%" == "" goto enter-input
if "%INPUT%" == "x" goto end
if "%INPUT%" == "X" goto end

set /A isOne = "(%INPUT% & 1) / 1"
set /A isTwo = "(%INPUT% & 2) / 2"
set /A isThree = "(%INPUT% & 4) / 4"
set /A isFour = "(%INPUT% & 8) / 8"

if %isOne% == 1 echo Selection one
if %isTwo% == 1 echo Selection two
if %isThree% == 1 echo Selection three
if %isFour% == 1 echo Selection four

echo Done
:end
```

Comment: If you add a line, `SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion`, after `@echo off` then the `set INPUT=` line wouldn't be needed. Also, what's the `%=%` in the `set /P` statement doing? Lastly, you may want to remove the spaces from the ` == ` ifs; batch files don't really like those.

Answer (score 8):

It is possible to do the bit-wise math and the comparison all in one statement. The trick is to intentionally create a divide by zero error if the result is what you are looking for. Of course stderr should be redirected to nul, and the `||` operator is used to test for the error condition (indicating TRUE).

This technique eliminates the need for any intermediate variable.

```
@echo off
:enter-input
set "input="
echo(
echo Please enter a number between 1 and 15:
echo 1 = Selection one
echo 2 = Selection two
echo 4 = Selection three
echo 8 = Selection four
echo x = Quit

set /P INPUT=Type number:

if not defined input goto enter-input
if /i "%input%" == "X" exit /b

2>nul (
  set /a "1/(1-(input&1))" || echo Selection one
  set /a "1/(2-(input&2))" || echo Selection two
  set /a 1/(4-(input^&4^)^) || echo Selection three
  set /a 1/(8-(input^&8^)^) || echo Selection four
)
pause
goto enter-input
```

The accepted answer never stated the somewhat obvious: Special characters like `&` and `)` must be either escaped or quoted within the SET /A computation. I intentionally demonstrated both techniques in the example above.

---

**EDIT:** The logic can be made even simpler by reversing the logic (divide by zero if false) and using the `&&` operator.

```
2>nul (
  set /a "1/(input&1)" && echo Selection one
  set /a "1/(input&2)" && echo Selection two
  set /a 1/(input^&4^) && echo Selection three
  set /a 1/(input^&8^) && echo Selection four
)
```

Answer (score 1):

For bitwise AND, put expression in quotes to avoid error 
eg. `set /a "48 & 23"`

Answer (score 0):

```
SET LEFT = 1
SET RIGHT = 2
SET /A RESULT = %LEFT% & %RIGHT%
```

Please escape the ampersand character (&) with a '^' if you try it directly in cmd.exe.